# Get the first and last visible element of widows phone listbox

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7.1

How i can get the first and last visible element of windows phone listbox.My requirement is to load the list items based on scrolling. More detail : I am using a longlist selector for displaying items. It contains two hierarchy of lists. One list is for displaying the header items and another is for displaying the grouped item. While initial loading i will get the title and the url’s for fetching the child items of list. So here i need to load this list items(children) based on scrolling. My list contains huge no of items because of this i adopted this method. Please any one share some ideas to implement this in my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [Colin's solution](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/03/metro-in-motion-part-2-peel-animations/).

Here is the relevant snippet:

```
VirtualizingStackPanel vsp = itemsControl.Descendants<VirtualizingStackPanel>()
                                         .First() as VirtualizingStackPanel;

// iterate over each of the items in view
int firstVisibleItem = (int)vsp.VerticalOffset;
int visibleItemCount = (int)vsp.ViewportHeight;
```

I have used it before and it works. Please note that both properties are regular properties and not dependency properties. In case you want to bind to them.